# how to remove data-plugin attribute by using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

i tried to come out a script where when click on button disabled the calendar wont show and click on enable the calendar will show up again. for disabled function, i use the method readonly instead disable, but how can i remove the data-plugin attribute?

Demo site : https://test.e-cover.com.my/pib/test/test.jsp

Browser use : Chrome

```
  <%for(int i =0; i<3; i++){%>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon wb-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="DOB_<%=i%>" id="DOB_<%=i%>" value="" class="form-control tt-input brdr1" data-plugin="datepicker" maxlength="10">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <%} %>

<input type="button" value="disabled" onclick="fnDisable()">
<input type="button" value="enable" onclick="fnEnable()">
```

### script

```
function fnEnable()
{

    for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
      document.getElementById("DOB_"+i).readOnly = false;
       document.getElementById("DOB_"+i).style.backgroundColor ="#FFFFFF";
    }
}

function fnDisable()
{
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
  { var v = document.getElementById("DOB_"+i);
    document.getElementById("DOB_"+i).readOnly = true;
    document.getElementById("DOB_"+i).style.backgroundColor ="#DDDDDD";


    //v.removeAttribute("data-plugin");
    //delete v.dataset.plugin;
   }
}
```

neither this `removeAttribute("data_plugin");`or this work `delete v.dataset.plugin;`.

Comment: `.removeAttribute("data-plugin")` needs a hyphen in `data-plugin`, not an underscore. But in any case, I wonder if the calendar plugin even notices if that attribute is removed - wouldn't it initialise when the page first loads, rather than trying to monitor dynamic attribute changes? I think that's where the issue lies, not in `.removeAttribute()` itself not working.

Comment: Done for the changes, yet the calendar still show up. Hmm, so is there any other method i can use to hide the calendar  if .removeAttribute() cannot be use?

Answer (score 1):

`delete v.dataset.plugin` should remove the data attribute. your problem is not the data attribute. basically, because the Calendar widget has already loaded on the page. the widget has been initialized and has reference to the DOM elements.
setting the `readOnly` flag to true only disables changing the content, not the click handler.

**Solution:**
You need to insert a "disabled" attribute to your input box to disable interactions.

to disable: `element.disabled = true;`
to enable: `element.removeAttribute('disabled');`